# Split word when meet new line and space

Tags: regex, matlab

How do I split the paragraph in word by words which store in each array? I could only able to split the words when meeting the space between each word, but could not split it when meet the new line. The words will combine together when meeting new line (e.g.: the last word of 1st line combine together with the 1st word of second line)

```
word_newLine = regexp(CharData, '\n', 'split')

word = regexp(word_newLine, ' ', 'split')
```

the "CharData"

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the function [`strsplit`](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html), you can split a string with multiple delimiters.

For example, you can split your paragraph in this manner:

```
words = strsplit(CharData, {' ','\n'});
```

**EDIT**

As stated in a comment, `strsplit` came with Matlab 2013. Before that version, one possibility is indeed to use `regexp`, in the following manner:

```
words = regexp(CharData,'\s+','split');
```

It splits the char array from white spaces (spaces, tabs, carriage return).

Comment: I get the error "??? Undefined function or method
'strsplit' for input arguments of
type 'cell'.

Error in ==> f19 at 10
    words = strsplit(CharData, {'
    ','\n'});"

got any ideas how to split both of the newline and whitespace together?

my "CharData" store a paragraph in array

Comment: @user3340270 What is EXACTLY the type of your `CharData`? (you can use function `class` for that) Is it an array of chars? A cell array of chars?

Comment: @user3340270 Thx for the screenshort, but could you please post the code you are using to load this data in the variable `CharData`? I must understand what is the exact type of this variable to help you more.

Comment: this is the full code for my question at here,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501856/how-to-get-rid-of-the-punctuation-and-check-the-spelling-error

Comment: @user3340270 I cannot reproduce your problem. I load with `fread` the file into `CharData`, then we have a char array. My solution works fine with Matlab2013. Maybe in your computer, `CharData` is a cell array of chars, so try `words = strsplit(CharData{:}, {' ','\n'});`.

Comment: i am using Matlab 2008b, i have a lot of problem with it, but all is settle, now just left this 1, it still return me the error, "??? Cell contents reference from a
non-cell array object.

Error in ==> f20 at 8
    word = strsplit(CharData{:}, {'
    ','\n'});
 "

Comment: Matlab 2008b do not support strsplit, http://www.dynare.org/DynareWiki/MatlabVersionsCompatibility
so any other method that I can used to solve this, I really need a help for this.if i want to maintain using matlab2008b, then i have to use this toolkit to solve it? git any other method that i only need to modify the code?

Comment: @user3340270 Thank you for pointing out that `strsplit` is quite new. I've editted my answer to use only compliant functions with R2008